# MongooseJS find if in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongojs

I have a foreign key field in an array:

```
const passageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    input: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Passage'
    }],
});
```

And I have a passage:

```
var passage = Passage.findOne({_id: passageID});
```

And I want to find all passages that have this passage as one of its inputs.

```
var passages = Passage.find({
        //find if in array
        input: passage //would work if it wasn't an array in schema
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if data type == array
you could use `$in`
for your query

here's the example

```html
var passages = Passage.find({
    input: { $in: [passage] }
});
```

also note, please be careful for using `var` in javascript